# ImportError while running cgi-bin on localhost - undefined symbol: lo_truncate64

Tags: python, postgresql, cgi, postgresql-9.3, cgi-bin

I'm trying to run a cgi-bin site on localhost. And I get the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: lo_truncate64
```

[image]

My current PostgreSQL version is 9.4.5.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by Ali Nikneshan under now deleted answer saved me couple times already when I had this same problem. Not sure why it was deleted, but here I am reposting it in hopes it helps someone:

```
pip install -U --no-cache-dir --force psycopg2
```